# Axiomatic introduction of the geometric product (Clifford Algebra)

Tags: clifford-algebras

While reading "Introduction to Clifford Algebra" by John Denker ([html version](http://www.av8n.com/physics/clifford-intro.htm) or [pdf version](http://www.av8n.com/physics/clifford-intro.pdf)), I have trouble to understand the generalization of the geometric product from *vectors* to general *clifs*. In particular I dont see where [equation (24)](http://www.av8n.com/physics/clifford-intro.htm#eq-example-terms) comes from. That equations states that from $A:=γ_1∧γ_2$ and $B:=(γ_2 + γ_3)∧(γ_4 + γ_1)$ should follow the geometric product:
$$AB = 1 + γ_1γ_4 + γ_2γ_3 +  γ_1 γ_2 γ_3 γ_4.$$

It is unclear to me what terms like $γ_1γ_4$ mean and where the overall expression comes from.

Comment: So $\gamma_1\gamma_4$ is the product of those two elements... what is unclear about the meaning, might I ask? I will see if I can explain the overall expression later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the identity for vectors $v,w$ that $vw=v\cdot w + v\wedge w$ and the corollary that $vw=v\wedge w=-wv$ if $w\perp v$, you get

$$(\gamma_1\wedge\gamma_2)((\gamma_2 + \gamma_3)\wedge(\gamma_4 + \gamma_1))\\ 
=\gamma_1\gamma_2((\gamma_2+\gamma_3)(\gamma_4+\gamma_1)-(\gamma_2+\gamma_3)\cdot(\gamma_4+\gamma_1))\\
\gamma_1\gamma_2(\gamma_2\gamma_4+\gamma_2\gamma_1+\gamma_3\gamma_4+\gamma_3\gamma_1-0)\\
=\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_2\gamma_4+\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_2\gamma_1+\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3\gamma_4+\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3\gamma_1\\
=\gamma_1\gamma_4+1+\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3\gamma_4+\gamma_2\gamma_3$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are vectors then
$$
\gamma_1 \gamma_2= \gamma_1 \ast \gamma_2 + \gamma_1 \wedge \gamma_2
$$
that is the geometric product is decomposed as a sum of a scalar and wedge product.
The object $ \gamma_1 \wedge \gamma_2$ is a directed plane element, i.e. a bivector, while $\gamma_1 \ast \gamma_2$ is a number.